# How to repeat cell value X times in google sheet using arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to repeat the text in cell `A3:A5` for `X` times where `X = value in cell B3:B5`. The out put should start from cell `A8`. Cell `A8:A21` in the screenshot above is the expected output. May I know how should I achieve this by using `ARRAYFORMULA`? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I was trying to use `REPT` but the output horizontally in one cell although I wrap the formula with `TRANSPOSE`

Comment: be careful that you are not describing an xyproblem.  When people ask for this, they are usually trying to reconfigure data laid out in a horizontal fashion into data that is more vertically oriented.   There are much better ways to do it all at once, but you need to describe and show the entire problem.
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this formula in A8:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(A3:A5&"|",B3:B5),"|",1,1)),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"))`

`REPT` will repeat each value in A3:A5 with an appended pipe symbol ("|") however many times are in the corresponding cells B3:B5. So if A3 is "Exercise 1" and B3 is 3, `REPT` will produce `Exercise 1|Exercise 1|Exercise 1` for that row, etc.

`SPLIT` will then split each of those strings apart at the "|" symbol.

`FLATTEN` will form one column of all of the above.

`QUERY` will eliminate any null (i.e, "blank") results in the list, so that only non-null values are left.

**UPDATE**

Using new functionality made available since the original post date:

`=ArrayFormula(TOCOL(SPLIT(REPT(A3:A5&"|",B3:B5),"|"), 1))`

Comment: Thanks Erik! May I know what is the reason for putting the parameter `1,1` for `SPLIT` function?

Comment: Each 1 is the same as TRUE for its parameter. The first parameter is "Split by each instance of this symbol?" In this case, it could have been a 1 or a 0, because the result would have been the same; but you have to include that first parameter in order to get to the second one, which is the important one. The second parameter is "Omit null cells that may be caused by the SPLIT?" And we do want nulls omitted. Technically, if we left out the "1, 1" the QUERY would have deleted the nulls. But I like to make each piece work fully within itself.